# Rails Cart Return Product Quantities on Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cart

I am new to rails and have a simple product store site. When a user adds a product to their cart or updates the line_item quantities in the cart, it will add/remove from the base product quantity as necessary. However, when they empty their cart (delete/destroy cart), it does not restore the base product quantity as if they did not buy anything. How do I update the destroy method to return the line_items listed back to the original product quantity?

line_items_controller.rb - Sample method to completely empty one product line_item in cart and increase base product quantity:

```
def empty
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.empty_product(product)
  @total = @line_item.quantity
  product.increment!(:quantity, @total)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Product removed.' }
      format.js
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

carts/show.html.erb - Call to destroy/empty cart:

```
<%= link_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to empty your cart?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger whiteText' %>
```

carts_controller.rb - Current method to destroy cart:

```
def destroy
  @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Cart was emptied.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

carts_controller.rb - What I'm trying to do (I think there may be an issue with this as it does not know how to resolve product = Product.find(params[:product_id])):

```
def destroy
  @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    @cart.line_items.each do
      product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      @total = @line_item.quantity
      product.increment!(:quantity, @total)
    end
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Cart was emptied.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Tried to change the destroy method:

```
def destroy
  if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    @cart.line_items.each do |l|
      product = Product.where(:id => l.product_id)
      @total = @l.quantity
      product.increment!(:quantity, @total)
    end
    @cart.destroy
  end
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Cart was emptied.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

It gives me the following error, even though I was able to use increment! on product quantity in the line_items_controller:

```
undefined method `increment!' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb5ad1b4>
```

Also tried calling the path straight into the carts controller method. It shows cart successfully emptied, but does not return the product quantity to what it should be like when I call this same method in the html:

```
if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
  @cart.line_items.each do |l|
    empty_line_item_path(product_id: l.product)
  end
  @cart.destroy
end
```

Comment: You can store the product_id in the line item (line_item belongs to product) so that you don't need to pass the product id in params.

Comment: See edit in original question.

Comment: It isn't very clear; can you isolate the code which raises the error reproducing it in the rails console

Comment: The error is on product.increment!(:quantity, @total) in the destroy method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the question about destroy, you can actually do this at the model level.

On your LineItem model you can do...

```
before_destroy { |record| record.product.increment!(:quantity, record.quantity }
```

This assumes the LineItem has...

```
belongs_to :product
```

And will ensure the product quantity is updated regardless of where the line_item record is destroyed.

Comment: This works great, but when checkout has been completed, it will return the product quantities that were in the cart back to the original product. Meaning, what is put in the cart is remove from the product quantity, but then returned after checkout. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: So you delete the fulfilled orders?  Ok, you can perhaps handle that by checking the cart status. Or you can do "delete" instead of "destroy" which won't do the callbacks.  One possible solution is in my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

For your error after your EDIT part, you have...

```
  product = Product.where(:id => l.product_id)
  @total = @l.quantity
  product.increment!(:quantity, @total)
```

The `where` method doesn't return a single product, it returns a relation of productions (which likely only contain one product anyway).

Better would be...

```
  product = Product.find_by(:id => l.product_id)
  @total = @l.quantity
  product.increment!(:quantity, @total)
```

...which will return a product object.

Comment: This is the route I needed to go to find the product in this controller. Thanks!